# UTF-8 decoding doesn't work

Tags: java, android, utf-8, mina

I'm working on a client-server application with an Android-client and a Java-server-implementation using Apache mina. The application must be able to handle German "Umlaute" (e.g. 'ä', 'ö', 'ü'). In both parts of the application I'm using UTF-8 for encoding and decoding. But when I send a String containing an umlaut from the client to the server the String on the server has a '?' instead of the umlaut. The weird thing is that if I send a String from the server to the client, all characters are displayed in the right way. 
Here's my server-code:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message)
        throws Exception {
    super.messageReceived(session, message);
    String mess = (String) message;
    System.out.println(mess);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String command = gson.fromJson(mess, CommandObject.class).getCommand();
    JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject) jParser.parse(mess);
    jsonObj = jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("object");
    String json = jsonObj.toString();
    String answer = this.commandMap.get(command).execute(json);
    session.write(answer);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor(1);
    DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder filterChain = acceptor.getFilterChain();
    ProtocolCodecFilter filter = new ProtocolCodecFilter(
            new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    filterChain.addLast("codec", filter);
    acceptor.setHandler(new IOHandler());
    acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(4630));
}
```

And here is the code I use to send data from the client:

```
private static final Charset ENC_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");


public TCPSocket(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream(), TCPSocket.ENC_CHARSET));
    this.outStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            socket.getOutputStream(), TCPSocket.ENC_CHARSET));
}

public void sendLine(final String line) throws IOException {
    this.outStream.write(line);
    this.outStream.newLine();
    this.outStream.flush();
}

public String receiveLine() throws IOException {
    return this.inStream.readLine();
}
```

Does anybody know what the problem is here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try not to send utf-8 but the windows or iso-##### charset. (sory dont know exactly how they are named)

Comment: Or don't specify an encoding for the output stream.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but nothing helped. The umlaut is still displayed as a '?' on the server. I found out that additional to not displaying the umlauts the right way a non-visible character gets appended at the end of the String which causes a MalFormedJsonException in Gson.

Comment: If ä is displayed on the server as ? and the server would not understand utf-8 then you are not sending utf-8. If you send ä in utf-8 two bytes will be send. The server will show two charakters then... hmmm... or neglects the other yes...

Comment: Try with `...write(line.getBytes("UTF-8));`. Whis iso set did you use?

Comment: If you do a `round trip` and after `String mess=...` return with `session.write(mess);` does a ä come back ok?

Comment: Found the problem! The communication part was fine the whole time. The System.out.println(mess) in the beginning of the messageReceived-Method just printed it the wrong way which got me a little confused. The only problem I had now was the trailing non-visible character which caused an exception in the Gson()-lib. I still don't get where this trailing character comes from. It seems like it's only there if there is an umlaut (or maybe some other unusual characters) somewhere in the String. But thanks for your help!